# FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Australia/Canberra"

Tags: database, postgresql-9.3, psql, confluence

I have tried to upgrade my 9.3.5 Postgresql to 9.3.7, I have used the source to make build from source and then I have pointed to the right version to start. I am using this D.B for Confluence 5.6.6 and I keep getting this

`FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Australia/Canberra"`

I have noticed that shared library in 9.3.5 differs from 9.3.7, there is no timezone directory in the old version but both version contain timezonesets which are same.

Answer (score 0):

The recognized time zone names are listed in the `pg_timezone_names` view (see [Section 45.67](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html)).

Australia/Canberra is in `pg_timezone_names` ?

Comment: The thing is I have set my DB timezone to GMT as well as my server. I dont understand where this "Australia/Canberra" coming from. pg_timezone_names is a view so I have no idea where does the DB retrieve these records. Do you have any suggestions?